# In ggplot, how can I get two legends ("gradient" type) for stat_bin2d?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, legend

Here I have two 'clusters', and just one legend.

How can I get two "density" legends with two different color gradients?

I have tried `group` but it does not work.

[image]

The following code generated the above graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(1000,1,.1),rnorm(1000,3,.1)),
                 y=c(rnorm(1000,1,1),rnorm(1000,3,1)),
                 type=c(rep('a',1000),rep('b',1000)))

plot( ggplot(df) + 
      stat_bin2d(aes(x,y,fill=..density..,group='type')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to specify more than one fill gradient. But here's a work around that uses different transparency levels to simulate the gradient, leaving fill available to be mapped with type:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = type)) + 
  stat_bin2d(aes(alpha = ..density..)) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(1, 0.1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: different colours]

Comment: In my opinion there is a subtle problem with the graph: highest density are mapped to white (or, at least, to a very 'pale' color) but also the background of the graph is white! I think that a black background would solve the issue.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson To reverse the alpha scale, you can set the range back to `c(0.1, 1)`. (I was trying to imitate the dark-light range of the fill gradient.)

Answer (score 3):

Using `alpha = ..density..` does the trick:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y) ) + 
  stat_bin2d(mapping= aes(alpha = ..density.., fill = type))
```

[image]

A bit more aesthetically using `stat_density2d` e.g.:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y) ) + 
  stat_density2d(mapping= aes(alpha = ..level.., color= type), geom="contour", bins=6, size= 2)
```

[image]