# Two seperate color gradient color scales on one ggplot2 map

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to plot a map that has two different color scales on it for different countries.

Example of my data:

```
>df
         country responses         area
1         Canada       150 northamerica
2  United States        70 northamerica
3         Mexico        65 northamerica
4        Germany       120       europe
5         France        55       europe
6          Spain        71       europe
```

I would like there to be one gradient (blues) showing the number of responses for `northamerica` and another one (reds) showing the number of responses for `europe` on the same world map.

I have tried subsetting the data and doing two different `geom_map` lines but I get `Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale.`

```
na <- df[df$area=="northamerica",]
euro <- df[df$area=="europe",]

library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
data(wrld_simpl)
wrld_simpl@data$id <- wrld_simpl@data$NAME
wrld <- fortify(wrld_simpl, region="id")
wrld <- subset(wrld, id != "Antarctica")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=wrld, map=wrld, aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat),      fill="white", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=na, map=wrld, aes(map_id=country, fill=responses),  color="white", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "#56B1F7", name="Number of\nresponses\nNorth America")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=euro, map=wrld, aes(map_id=country, fill=responses),  color="white", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_continuous(high = "#67000d", low = "#fcbba1", name="Number of\nresponses\nEurope")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + labs(x="", y="")
gg <- gg + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
             panel.border = element_blank(),
             panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
             panel.grid = element_blank(),
             axis.text = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks = element_blank(),
             legend.position = "right")
gg
```

I just get the last color scale coded instead of both:

[image]

I can get the two sets of data to be different colors using this code (below) but I can not figure out how to get it to be scaled by the number of responses in this case.

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=wrld, map=wrld, aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat), fill="white", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=na, map=wrld, aes(map_id=country, fill=responses),  color="white", size=0.25, fill = "blue")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=euro, map=wrld, aes(map_id=country, fill=responses),  color="white", size=0.25, fill = "red")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + labs(x="", y="")
gg <- gg + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
             panel.border = element_blank(),
             panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
             panel.grid = element_blank(),
             axis.text = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks = element_blank(),
             legend.position = "right")
gg
```

Different colors for the two regions but not scaled by responses

[image]

I have tried other variations of code that would take a while to include here and some of them I would be embarrassed to show since I reached a point where I was just trying anything and everything. If anyone has any suggestions that would be wonderful. I would like to avoid making two maps and then putting them on top of each other but if it comes to it I will do that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi-  I have an idea for you, but I need a simple, reproducible data set in order to test this.  I found the `maptools` package to get `wrld_simpl`, but I'm getting errors when I try to run your fortify function.  My idea for you involves adjusting alpha.  If you can get it to work on your own, great - if not, you need to make a reproducible example.

Comment: This strikes me as something that `ggplot2` would discourage because it results in a visualization which is difficult to interpret and potentially misleading. It may give the impression that values are markedly different when they are not. You could generate 2 panels, zoomed into Europe and N. America respectively to highlight the regions but even then, I would not use different colour gradients.

Comment: A couple of options from answers to similar questions: [Make your own colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738083/2461552) and then use the "identity" scale or trick things by coloring by group [and then using alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46277622/2461552).

Comment: @MelissaKey Sorry about that.  I am new to this.  I just edited my question to include the packages.  You have to load `ggplot2` to fortify the map. I have been messing around with the alpha but I can not seem to get anything to work.      
@neilfws ok so if `ggplot2` won't let me do it do you have any other suggestions?       
@aosmith - I was just trying to assign my colors and using "identity" but couldn't seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you close to what you want.

```
# Other packages needed in order to to run this code
install.packages("rgeos", "mapproj")

ggplot() +
  geom_map(data=wrld, map=wrld, aes(map_id=id, x=long, y=lat),      fill="white", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25) +
  geom_map(data=df, map=wrld, aes(map_id=country, fill=area, alpha = responses),  color="white", size=0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#132B43", "#67000d")) + 
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.3, 1)) + 
  coord_map() +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "right"
```

The deepest color of each is constant from what you had, but I'm scaling the colors by changing their transparency instead of the lowest color, so I can't specify the lightest color.  I can adjust how transparent it is at the bottom  - and you can play with that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @MelissaKey.  This is a neat way to do it.  I am going to have to fiddle with it some more though as in my real data Canada as ~1000 more responses than any other country so it currently has Canada as dark and then all of the other countries are the palest color.  But thank you for getting me this far! I unfortunately do not have enough reputation points to click the up arrow - sorry.

Comment: use a log scale to address that one